# Proving this function is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic. Let $z_0 \in \Omega$ and define $$F(z)= \begin{cases} \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0} \qquad &\text{for } z \in \Omega \setminus \{z_0\} \\
f'(z_0) \qquad &\text{for } z=z_0\end{cases}.$$

How does one prove that $F$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$? This seems like a quite straightforward application of the definition, but I was advised that this is not the case. So I'm doubting how to prove this...

Comment: Do you know that holomorphic functions are locally equal to power series?

Comment: $F$ is holomorphic except perhaps at $z_0$, and it is continuous at $z_0$. This is enough to conclude holomorphy everywhere. You can prove this for example by expanding $f$ as a power series about $z_0$ (recall that holomorphy on an open set is equivalent to being analytic).

Comment: So the key is to write everything here as a power series?

Comment: You can also use Riemann's theorem on removable singularities.

Comment: @MartinR ah yes that we have seen I believe, how would i go about doing this?

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity. If $F$ is continuous at $z_0$ then the singularity is removable.